# Cannot display another map on map click listener event

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to create a page that loads a small google map and it is working fine. Now I want to add a map event click that shows a bigger div displaying another google map with the same lng and lat. The div is shown properly a google logo and a beige background color , but there is no map and I can't figure out the problem. I am working on visual studio 2012 and google map is shown using javascript.

Below is my code:

```
  var latlng;

        function initialize(lng, lat) {

            var myOptions = {
               zoom: 17,
               center: latlng,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: latlng,
               map: map,
               icon: "/Images/marker.png",
               title: "This is the place."
            });

            var contentString = 'Hello <strong>World</strong>!';
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: contentString 
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
               infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });

            document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.visibility = 'visible';

            map.addListener('click', function (e) {

            var myOptions2 = {
               zoom: 17,
               center: latlng,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map2 = new google.maps.Map(
              document.getElementById("modal-body"),
              myOptions2);

            var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: latlng,
               map: map2,
               icon: "/Images/marker.png",
               title: "This is the place."
            });

            var contentString2 = 'Hello <strong>World</strong>!';
            var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: contentString2
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function () {
               infowindow2.open(map2, marker2);
            });

           document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
               });
       }
```

Those are my divs where I am displaying my maps:

```
 <div id="map_canvas" class="mapDiv" style="visibility:hidden" > </div>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal" style="display: none">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span onclick="CloseMyDiv();" id="closeSpan" class="close">×</span>
        <br /><br />
        <div id="modal-body"  class="modal-body">
           Hello world !
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I repeat: modal-body changes when I click on map-canvas (by adding google logo and changing background color), but it is not displaying a map, and I tried to fill map in div before click event but still have the same problem.

Any hints?

Note: If I comment everything concerning map-canvas and I i show myModal div at onload event, map is displayed properly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Make sure `modal-body` have width and height set in CSS.

2.If the div containing the map, or it's parent, or it's parent's parent (any predecessor) has `display:none` set at some point, the map view won't initialise properly and you will only see gray map. I noticed that you show the modal only after the map is initialised. So for map to appear properly, either run this code

```
document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
```

before the `map2` initialisation, or trigger `resize` event on map after visibility change, which would reinitialise the map view:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map2,'resize');
```

Probably not relevant for your case, but you need to also `trigger` resize event on map if the map containing's div dimensions change.